# To display errors during onkeyup function

Tags: angular

```
 <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name = "user_last_name" 
 [(ngModel)]="user_last_name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9].*" minlength="3" required>

  <mat-error *ngIf="adduser.controls['user_last_name']?.errors?.pattern">
  This field is required</materror>
```

In the above code I want to display the error as soon has I typed in the textbox but this error is coming only when I ever clicked anywhere outside the textbox is this default property.

I am using angular 8

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup event to capture the input text,

```
<input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

Then in your component, inside the onKey() method write your validation logic.

```
onKey(event: any) {
    const pattern = ^[a-zA-Z0-9].*;
    // do your validation here
}
```